# Android:Creating UI Components and reusing it programmatically

Tags: android, user-interface, components

I have created one simple UI and set by id mainContainer2.
i want to  know if something like this is possible to reuse it inside a loop for example

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
LinearLayout mainContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
mainContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

TextView textoqualquer = new TextView(this);
textoqualquer.setText("textoqualquer");
mainContainer.addView(textoqualquer);

LinearLayout maincontainer = new LinearLayout(this);
maincontainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
maincontainer.findViewById(R.id.mainContainer2);



mainContainer.addView(maincontainer);

setContentView(mainContainer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what you are asking. But you can use the same xml ui wherever need by just inflating it like

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Then you can use the layout where ever needed.
Also in xml file you can reuse another xml layout by using either the 'include' or 'merge' tag
like

```
<include layout="@layout/okcancelbar_button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use layout inflater in this case. use

LinearLayout headerView = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_name, null);

This will give you complete parent layout of you layout and then you can reuse your complete view or reuse a part of that view by using

view_type my_view = (view_type)headerview.findviewbyid (R.id.view_name)